# How to install matplotlib venn diagrams in Python 3.4?

Tags: matplotlib, venn-diagram, matplotlib-venn

I tried to install matplotlib venn diagrams (with easy-install) in Python 3.4, but it keeps installing for python 2.7. Someone knows how to do it?

Comment: If you use `easy_install` from your Python2.7 distribution, it will install packages into your Python2.7 distribution. If you use `easy_install` from your Python3.4 distribution, it will install packages into your Python3.4 distribution. Make sure you invoke the correct `easy_install`.